# Running a Segue within a UITableViewCell Swift 2

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2, segue

I have a button within a UITableViewCell and need to perform a following to another View.
How can I do this?

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBAction func btnShowView(sender: AnyObject) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("seguePrincipalImagem")
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having the code on the cell directly (although you can also make it with delegation), you can add the code directly to your controller and bind the method to the button, something like this:

1. Create a function that perform the segue on your UIViewController

   ```
   func btnShowView(sender: AnyObject) {
       self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue_identifier",selder:nil)
   }
   ```
2. In the process of creating the cell that has the button (in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:):

   ```
   //Inside tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellIdentifier",indexPath) as! YourCustomTableViewCell
   cell.yourBtn.addTarget(self, action: "btnShowView", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
   //More code to configure cell...
   return cell
   ```

And that's it.